# Avoid status bar transparency while animating

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uianimation

I got the viewController with 2 elements:

1. view with labels and buttons
2. tableView

I'm getting the following animation by changing view's height constraint from 170 to 0 and than animating view.layoutIfNeeded() and tableView.layoutIfNeeded().

My goal is to hide menu when content offset of the tableView reaches some value.

**This works fine, except I got an overlay of status bar over the moving content from my view.** Are there any options to add a sublayer to status bar not to be transparent? Or any other suggestions?

Thanks!

[image: Animation scene]

Comment: you can out a put a solid black `20pt` high view there which makes the illusion the statusbar's transparency is gone; but for `UITableView` I would rather recommend to set the content edge inset by `(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, which is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: ^ What holex said. If you check out UIApplication documentation there is nothing about changing the background for status bar. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view, put it where the status bar will be, and set its background color to which ever color you require. For example:

```
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame)
statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

Or, set the content edge inset by `(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, which I would agree is a much more elegant solution, as suggested by @holex in the comments

Comment: Might also want to add a content inset for the top of the tableView

Comment: Why don't you use `statusBarFrame` directly?

Comment: @Sulthan thats just way too simple...I've updated my answer.

Comment: The problem is: those top buttons and labels are part of UIView, not the tableView. tableView starts with green/orange headers. So I think content inset wouldn't  help me in that case. Or did I missunderstood your idea?